# Intersection of nonempty compact sets are nonempty

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

**Question:**
If ${Sn}$ is a sequence of nonempty compact sets with $S_{n+1} ⊂ S_{n}$ for
every $n$, show that ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞
S_{n} \neq ∅$.

**My Attempt**
Choose $S_{k}$ from sequence ${Sn}$. Assume ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞ S_{n} = ∅$.

Such that no points inside $S_{k}$ are in unions of all the other $S_{n}$
Set $T_{\alpha} = S_{\alpha}^{c}$.

$S_{k}$ is contained in the open cover formed by several $T_{\alpha}$

Since $S_{k}$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover of several $T_{\alpha}$ that covers $S_{k}$.

This means $S_{k} ⊂ T_{\alpha_1}{\bigcap}T_{\alpha_2}{\bigcap}T_{\alpha_3}{\bigcap}....{\bigcap}T_{\alpha_n}$

This also implies $S_{k}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_1}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_2}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_3}{\bigcap}....{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_n} = ∅$

However, the condition says, $S_{n+1} ⊂ S_{n}$ which means $S_{k}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_1}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_2}{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_3}{\bigcap}....{\bigcap}S_{\alpha_n} = ∅$ is not possible, thus making contradiction.

Thus ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞
S_{n} \neq ∅$.

I'm not sure whether this would be the legitimate proof for this question, especially the last part about the contradiction. Could anyone verify or suggest a better method to address this question?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually not true in general you need that the the compact sets are also closed.
A simple counter example is the reals with the topology that has all sets of the form $(x,\infty)$ Any set of the form $[y,\infty)$ is going to be compact but it's not closed since the only closed sets are of the form $(-\infty,x]$. So taking the sequence of sets $([n,\infty) )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ then the intersection is empty even thought they are all compact. In a $T_2$ space like the real line with its standard topology all compact sets are closed. Your statement is true in this case.

Edit: I see that there are no general topology tags on your question. Just ignore this part if you haven't taken any introductory courses on point-set topology. The following proof works for the Real numbers because of the Heine-Borel Theorem which tells us compact sets are closed.

Proof: Given a sequence $S_n$ of decreasing non empty closed compact sets we can assume by taking a subsequence that it's strictly decreasing. assume that $\bigcap_{n} S_n=\emptyset$ then one defines an sequence of open sets as the complements  $A_n=S_n^c$ for $n \geq 2$ Using Demorgan $\bigcup A_n=\bigcup S_n^c=(\bigcap S_n)^c=X$ So it's an open cover of the entire topological space $X$ so it must also cover $S_1$ so there must be a finite open subcover of $S_1$ since it's compact. But $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n$ so if there is a finite subsequence there must be an $n$ such that $A_n$ covers $S_1$ Since $S_n\subseteq S_1$ and $A_n=S_n^c$ we get  $S_n=S_1\cap S_n=S_1\setminus S_n^c =S_1\setminus A_n=\emptyset$. But this contradicts the fact that all of the $S_n$ were non empty so the intersection can't be non empty.

Comment: How can we use compactness of $S_1$ here? since $A_n$ are open in $X$. And to use compactness of $S_1$ we need sets open in $S_1$.

Comment: @MeetPatel if the $A_n$ cover $S_1$ then $A_n\cap S_1$ will cover $S_1$ which are open in the subspace topology. Alternatively you may modify the definition of compact subset as being a subset $C$ of $X$ such that any open covering of $C$ with open set of $X$ admits a finite subcover. Then you verify that a subset is compact if and only if it is compact with respect to the subspace topology. The proof of this is essentially writing out the definitions.