# Small trouble trying to prove that If $(K_{\lambda \in L})$ is a chain of compact sets, then $\cap_{\lambda \in L}$ is compact and non-empty?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to answer the following problem:

> **Definition:** $(C_{ \lambda \in L})$ is a chain if given $\lambda, \mu$ we have $C_\lambda \supseteq C_\mu$ or $C_\mu \subseteq C_\lambda$.
>
> Show that If $(K_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in L}$ is a chain of compact sets, then $\cap_{\lambda \in L} K_{\lambda }$ is compact and non-empty.

And I found answers such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2340682/25805). The trouble for me is that in this problem, the index set seems to be arbitrary instead of $\Bbb{N}$ and we have $C_\lambda \subseteq C_\mu$ or $C_\mu \subseteq C_\lambda$, also other proofs I found in the site require the space to be Hausdorff. I'm confused if this would require a very different proof.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes. Thanks!

Comment: See the counterexample given in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4076026/592552